# Usage of a node module to post media on Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have found this module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api

I wanted to know if it was legal to post on instagram using an api.
Because the documentation only show GET method and not post

Comment: Nothing budy. Instagram just opened his API for some business companies.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api?locale=fr_FR

Comment: more info : https://instagrampartners.com/

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if it's legal but here is your code ( pip install instabot )

```
from instabot import Bot 
  
name = input("Image name + extensions : ")  

bot = Bot() 
bot.login(username = "user_name",  
          password = "user_password")

 
bot.upload_photo(name, 
#Put the photo in the same directory as this code
                 caption ="YOURCAPTION")
```